# Socket.io, Node.js: How can a javascript variable be passed to mysql query from in a javascript.js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, variables, socket.io

Socket.io, Node.js: How can a javascript variable be passed to mysql query from in a javascript.js?

There is an error when a variable of value `'222.222.222.222'`, is attempted to be passed into the mysql query, but not when a variable having a value of `'2'` is passed into the same mysql query.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This gives error:

```
var javascriptVariable = '222.222.222.222';

$query = 'INSERT INTO misc_table (misc_field) VALUES ('+javascriptVariable+')';

connection.query($query, function(err, rows, fields) {
if(err){
    console.log("An error ocurred performing the query.");
    return;
    }
    console.log("Query succesfully executed: ", rows);
    });
```

This does not give error:

```
var javascriptVariable = '2';

$query = 'INSERT INTO misc_table (misc_field) VALUES ('+javascriptVariable+')';

connection.query($query, function(err, rows, fields) {
if(err){
    console.log("An error ocurred performing the query.");
    return;
    }
    console.log("Query succesfully executed: ", rows);
    });
```

Comment: $query = 'INSERT INTO `misc_table` (misc_field) VALUES ('+javascriptVariable+')'; :)

Comment: This is kinda really basic just try to go over js basics again i'm guessing you need some problems there .

Comment: Edited the question, but still not working. There is an error: `An error ocurred performing the query.`

Comment: Oh aight i saw you get your answer and it's better to use it that way bdw. Thx @Vasyl Moskalov

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never ever thought to update databases in this manner.
First. In fact, you try to execute next code

```sql
INSERT INTO misc_table (misc_field) VALUES (222.222.222.222)
```

Second. This is the straight way to sql injection

Thrid. Try something like this

```
var javascriptVariable = '222.222.222.222';

let $query = 'INSERT INTO misc_table (misc_field) VALUES (?)';
connection.query(
    $query,[ javascriptVariable ], 
    function (...args) {
....
    }
);
```